# Parsing a Dataframe multiple ways

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to blow out the below dataset, so that every email address is a line item, including all the columns.

```
    PrimaryEmail     ShipToEmail       SoldToEmail    City
0  jack@jill.com            None  bridge@white.com   Maine
1  jill@jack.com            None              None  Jersey
2           None  frank@tony.com   listen@what.com    Blah
```

The results should be:

```
    PrimaryEmail     ShipToEmail       SoldToEmail    City             Role             Email                  UserID
0  jack@jill.com            None  bridge@white.com   Maine  Primary Contact     jack@jill.com     jack@jill.com__user
1  jill@jack.com            None              None  Jersey  Primary Contact     jill@jack.com     jill@jack.com__user
2           None  frank@tony.com   listen@what.com    Blah  Ship-To Contact    frank@tony.com    frank@tony.com__user
3  jack@jill.com            None  bridge@white.com   Maine  Sold-To Contact  bridge@white.com  bridge@white.com__user
4           None  frank@tony.com   listen@what.com    Blah  Sold-To Contact   listen@what.com   listen@what.com__user
```

I've created the function below which works great for a small set of data (like above), however when I get into 250K+ lines it will do the first function call fine, i.e.:

```
user_modifications(df.copy(deep=True),'PrimaryEmail','Primary Contact')
```

However, the rest of the function calls, for the other roles, are returning line items where the email address for that function are blank.

```
import pandas as pd

def user_modifications(__dataframe,__emailcolumn, __Role):
    __df=pd.DataFrame()
    __df.iloc[0:0]
    __df = __dataframe[__dataframe[__emailcolumn].notnull()].copy(deep=True)
    __df['Role'] = __Role
    __df['Email'] = __df[__emailcolumn]
    __df['UserID'] = __df[__emailcolumn] + '__user'
    return(__df)

def main():
    df=pd.DataFrame({'PrimaryEmail':['jack@jill.com','jill@jack.com',None],'ShipToEmail':[None,None,'frank@tony.com'],'SoldToEmail':['bridge@white.com',None,'listen@what.com'], 'City':['Maine','Jersey','Blah']})
    df_users = pd.concat([user_modifications(df.copy(deep=True),'PrimaryEmail','Primary Contact'),user_modifications(df.copy(deep=True),'ShipToEmail','Ship-To Contact'),user_modifications(df.copy(deep=True),'SoldToEmail','Sold-To Contact')], ignore_index=True)
    print(df_users)

main()
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue is in case any one stumbles on this thread.  When you perform a DataFrame filter like the one seen here:

```
__df = __dataframe[__dataframe[__emailcolumn].notnull()].copy(deep=True)
```

Pandas alters all null values to something else.  I'm still trying to figure out what.  I know in my original description I mentioned that it worked for smaller data set, and didn't for a larger one.  It was late at night, and maybe the smaller data set just sneaked by, with a scenario where it looked like it was working, but the data aligned just right.

Regardless:
Now I'm trying to figure out how to fill blanks with None

but when I replace the line with this:

```
__df = __dataframe[__dataframe[__emailcolumn].notnull()].fillna(None).copy(deep=True)
```

It throws an error that I need to specify a value to fill with.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are doing some additional copying of the dataframe. You can try as simple as possible, split the dataframe depending on the values in the first 3 columns, add the `Role` and `Email` columns and the concatenate everything together. Finally, the `UserID` column can be added.

```
primary_emails = df.loc[df['PrimaryEmail'].notnull()].copy()
primary_emails['Role'] = 'Primary Contact'
primary_emails['Email'] = df['PrimaryEmail']

ship_emails = df.loc[df['ShipToEmail'].notnull()].copy()
ship_emails['Role'] = 'Ship-To Contact'
ship_emails['Email'] = df['ShipToEmail']

sold_emails = df.loc[df['SoldToEmail'].notnull()].copy()
sold_emails['Role'] = 'Sold-To Contact'
sold_emails['Email'] = df['SoldToEmail']

df = pd.concat([primary_emails, ship_emails, sold_emails], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
df['UserId'] = df['Email'] + '__user'
```

This will give the wanted resulting dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for your response, yes I know that I can do what you described, however I'd like to do it via a function and understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.filter`, `melt` and `merge`:

```
df = df[df.ne("None")]
df2 = df.filter(like="Email").reset_index().melt(id_vars="index", 
                                                 var_name="Role", 
                                                 value_name="Email").dropna()
new_df = df.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_on="index").drop("index", 1)
```

Output:

```
    PrimaryEmail     ShipToEmail       SoldToEmail    City          Role  \
0  jack@jill.com             NaN  bridge@white.com   Maine  PrimaryEmail   
6  jack@jill.com             NaN  bridge@white.com   Maine   SoldToEmail   
1  jill@jack.com             NaN               NaN  Jersey  PrimaryEmail   
5            NaN  frank@tony.com   listen@what.com    Blah   ShipToEmail   
8            NaN  frank@tony.com   listen@what.com    Blah   SoldToEmail   

              Email  
0     jack@jill.com  
6  bridge@white.com  
1     jill@jack.com  
5    frank@tony.com  
8   listen@what.com
```

Then modify the new columns as desired:

```
new_df["Role"] = new_df["Role"].str.replace("Email", " Contact")
new_df["UserID"] = new_df["Email"] + "__user"
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
    PrimaryEmail     ShipToEmail       SoldToEmail    City             Role  \
0  jack@jill.com             NaN  bridge@white.com   Maine  Primary Contact   
6  jack@jill.com             NaN  bridge@white.com   Maine   SoldTo Contact   
1  jill@jack.com             NaN               NaN  Jersey  Primary Contact   
5            NaN  frank@tony.com   listen@what.com    Blah   ShipTo Contact   
8            NaN  frank@tony.com   listen@what.com    Blah   SoldTo Contact   

              Email                  UserID  
0     jack@jill.com     jack@jill.com__user  
6  bridge@white.com  bridge@white.com__user  
1     jill@jack.com     jill@jack.com__user  
5    frank@tony.com    frank@tony.com__user  
8   listen@what.com   listen@what.com__user
```